# Tabbing off a recently disabled element with a react-testing-library does not continue the tab order, how to emulate the browser tab order?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility, react-testing-library

I have a very simple test for a component with two buttons, and some other elements.

A minimal example would be:

```js
const { useState, useMemo } = React;
const { Button } = window['MaterialUI'];

const MyExample = () => {
  const [lightBulbs, setLightBulbs] = useState(Array.from(Array(10)).map((id, index) => {
    return { id: index.toString(), status: 'off'}
}));

  const allOn = useMemo(
    () => lightBulbs.every(bulb => bulb.status === 'on'),
    [lightBulbs]
  );
  const allOff = useMemo(
    () => lightBulbs.every(bulb => bulb.status === 'off'),
    [lightBulbs]
  );

  const switchOn = () =>
    setLightBulbs(prevBulbs =>
      prevBulbs.map(bulb => ({ ...bulb, status: 'on' }))
    );
  const switchOff = () =>
    setLightBulbs(prevBulbs =>
      prevBulbs.map(bulb => ({ ...bulb, status: 'off' }))
    );
  const switchBulb = bulbId => () =>
    setLightBulbs(prevBulbs =>
      prevBulbs.map(bulb =>
        bulb.id === bulbId
          ? { ...bulb, status: bulb.status === 'off' ? 'on' : 'off' }
          : bulb
      )
    );

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Button id='firstButton' onClick={() => alert('wrong button')}>
          Alert
        </Button>
        <Button id='secondButton' disabled={allOn} onClick={switchOn}>
          All On
        </Button>
        <Button id='thirdButton' disabled={allOff} onClick={switchOff}>
          All Off
        </Button>
      </div>
      <ul>
        {lightBulbs.map(bulb => (
          <li key={bulb.id}>
            <span>{"bulb with id "+bulb.id+" is "+bulb.status}</span>
            <Button onClick={switchBulb(bulb.id)}>
              Switch bulb {bulb.status === 'off' ? 'on' : 'off'}
            </Button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyExample), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my test I want to:

1. Tab from the 'firstButton' with `userEvent.tab()` to the *All On* button
2. Press the *All On* button with `userEvent.keyboard('{Enter}')`
3. Tab to the *All Off* button
4. Press the *All Off* button with `userEvent.keyboard('{Enter}')`

In the browser this works, but when using `rect-testing-library` in a test suite, the second tab *goes back to the 'firstButton'*:

```
test('can click all the buttons', () => {
  expect(document.body).toHaveFocus(); // sanity check
  userEvent.tab(); // tab past the 'first button'
  expect(screen.queryByRole('button', { name: 'All On' })).toHaveFocus()
  userEvent.keyboard('{Enter}'); // press button
  expect(screen.queryByRole('button', { name: 'All On' })).toBeDisabled() // should now be disabled

  userEvent.tab(); // tab off the 'second button', named 'All On'
  expect(screen.queryByRole('button', { name: 'All Off' })).toHaveFocus()
  userEvent.keyboard('{Enter}');
  expect(screen.queryByRole('button', { name: 'All Off' })).toBeDisabled() // should now be disabled
});
```

I can't understand why they behave differently?

Answer (score 1):

It must have to do with the fact that the button under focus becomes `disabled`.

That’s not a good pattern. [Focus needs to be visible at all times](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/focus-visible.html), but a `disabled` button cannot receive focus, and in this case the focus simply becomes invisible due to missing styles in Material UI.

Once you press *All On*, you will notice that focus simply disappears.

#### Why might React testing behave differently?

There is no single “the browser”. There are plenty of browsers, in tech-terms *user agents*, and their behavior is based on [Web Standards](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Web_standards). This, in turn, includes testing libraries like *react testing library*, which try to emulate browsers’ behavior.

Since the demonstrated solution is breaking accessibility rules, it‘s quite likely that the Web Standards don’t define the case of a focused element becoming inactive.

When the specification is unclear, user agents can decide how to handle the undefined case, and might decide to do so different to other user agents/browsers.

Your browser appears to keep focus on the button, even if that’s not visible. *React testing library* might simply *loose focus* once the button becomes disabled. This would result in the next <kbd>Tab</kbd> to put focus on the first interactive element, which is the *Alert* button.

The lack for a Material UI style that would make focus on the disabled button visible is another hint that this is an undefined case.

#### More accessible solutions

- programmatically set focus to the other button after click
- do not disable the buttons

I thought of using a [`switch` pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/switch/) as well, because it implies an action and not simply checking a state, but it does not allow for a `mixed` state that would be necessary once only some bulbs are on.

Comment: I'm not sure what your trying to say. This isn't about material-ui styles, and I'm not sure what you mean by "react testing might even remove focus from an element that becomes inactive, and put it on the document"... I don't think either of your solutions make sense for me.

Comment: Fair enough, I modified my answer and tried to fit it more to your question which is more limited to how to test, than to the test subject itself. Does that help?

Comment: That is much better. I'll need to double check when I'm in work Monday.